# Registry Key not writing, no error messages C#

Tags: c#

When I press the "Patch" button which is referred to button1 it will run this code

```
var registry = Registry.CurrentUser;
var key =
    registry.OpenSubKey(
        @"SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID", true);

//create a new key 
key.CreateSubKey("{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}");
registry.OpenSubKey(
        @"Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}");
key.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32");
registry.OpenSubKey(
        @"Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32");
key.SetValue("(Default)", "");
key.Close();
```

There is no error, but also no new key in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 32-bit CLSID and 64-bit CLSID are different keys, and will be shown depending on the bitness of the `regedit` you opened to view it. Make sure your application has the right bitness and that you're looking in the right place.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37110680/2485966

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh thank you, I didn't notice that. Is there a way to write it into the 32-bit CLSID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your OP creates the following registry subkey:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}
```

**Note**: If using the Registry Editor (regedit), it may be necessary to Refresh (View => Refresh) to see the new entry.

However, in your OP you haven't called `Dispose`.

According to [RegistryKey.CreateSubKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey?view=net-6.0)

> **Returns**
>
> RegistryKey The newly created subkey, or null if the operation failed.
> If a zero-length string is specified for subkey, the current
> RegistryKey object is returned.

Try the following:

```
private string AddRegSubkey(RegistryView regView = RegistryView.Registry64)
{
    using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.CurrentUser, regView))
    {
        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID", true))
        {
            string clsidGuid = "{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}";
            using (RegistryKey subkeyClsGuid = subkey.CreateSubKey(clsidGuid))
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkeyInprocServer32 = subkeyClsGuid.CreateSubKey("InprocServer32"))
                {
                    return $"Registry key '{System.IO.Path.Combine(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID", clsidGuid, "InprocServer32")}'  created.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Is64BitProcess: {Environment.Is64BitProcess.ToString()}");
string result = AddRegSubkey(RegistryView.Registry64);
//string result = AddRegSubkey(RegistryView.Registry32);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"result: {result}");
```

**Resources**:

- [RegistryKey.CreateSubKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey?view=net-6.0)
- [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- [RegistryView Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=net-6.0)