# Using C# to edit value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c#

I have a WPF application that is trying to audit registry values. I am able to read the value in HKLM, however, if the value needs to be changed I am hit with a UnauthorizedAccess error. I have an app.manifest file that is requiring the application to run as administrator. I also launch the application as admin.

Here is what I have in this function:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\State");

if (key != null)
{
    int value = (int)key.GetValue("UEFISecureBootEnabled");

    if (value == 0)
    {
        key.SetValue("UEFISecureBootEnabled", 1);
    }
}
```

app.manifest  file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I am new to C# so I am wading my way through this. I have read up on the topic and everyone seems to say that editing the app.manifest file to require administrator is the way to fix this but it does not work on mine.
I tried launching the app as administrator, editing the app.manifest file to require administrator and still I am getting the `UnauthorizedAccess` error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [RegistryKey.OpenSubKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=net-6.0#microsoft-win32-registrykey-opensubkey(system-string-system-boolean)) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71500768/10024425

Comment: From the documentation of OpenSubKey(string): "Retrieves a subkey as read-only." You need to use one of the other overloadss.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the user being used to run the application has administrative access on the machine requiring the registry changes.

Can you try editing the registry value manually by running regedit with the same user account being used to run the application with as a test?