# Add string value to Run of Current user into Windows registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I know there are a lot of similar topics on SO about this and I have tried most of the solutions without success. I want to create a string value for the startup of application on Windows start in current user registry. So I have created a class for that purpose. While looking at output provided by code

```
    Debug.WriteLine(subKey + " -- " + applicationPath);

    foreach (string s in names)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(" ->>> " + s);
    }
```

I can see my application has been added. However while trying to Refresh or open close or restart my computer, I do not see this string value in my Registry path. Why so and how to fix it? Does this code work for others?

My application is 64 bit. I have tried also to change code to Local Machine and with admin rights string value is created properly in Registry path for Local Machine. However I do not want to run my application with admin rights all the time this parameter needs to be changed from application settings. For that reason I would like to use Current user. Also I have tried to do it with SID `GetCurrentUserSid()` that got SID correctly, but was not able to create string value in proper path either.

Here is my current class:

```
public class WindowsStartupManager : IWindowsStartupManager
{
  private const string RegistryKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

  public bool IsStartupEnabled()
  {
    string applicationName = GetApplicationName();

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath))
    {
      if (key != null)
      {
        return key.GetValue(applicationName) != null;
      }
      else
      {
        // Handle the case where the Registry key is not found
        return false; 
      }
    }
  }

  public void EnableStartup()
  {
    string applicationName = GetApplicationName();
    string applicationPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    string currentUserSid = GetCurrentUserSid();

    using (RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, this.GetRegistryView()))
    {
      using (RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
      {
        subKey.SetValue(applicationName, applicationPath, RegistryValueKind.String);

        string[] names = subKey.GetValueNames();

        Debug.WriteLine(subKey + " -- " + applicationPath);

        foreach (string s in names)
        {
          Debug.WriteLine(" ->>> " + s);
        }

        subKey.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }

  public void DisableStartup()
  {
    string applicationName = GetApplicationName();
    string applicationPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    string currentUserSid = GetCurrentUserSid();

    try
    {
      RegistryKey myKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, this.GetRegistryView());
      {
        using (RegistryKey subKey = myKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl))
        {
          subKey.DeleteValue(applicationName, false);

          string[] names = subKey.GetValueNames();

          Debug.WriteLine(subKey);

          foreach (string s in names)
          {
            Debug.WriteLine(" - " + s);
          }

          subKey.Close();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Handle or log the exception
      Console.WriteLine("Failed to disable startup: " + ex.Message);
    }
  }

  public string GetApplicationName()
  {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    return assembly.GetName().Name;
  }

  public string GetApplicationPath()
  {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
  }

  private RegistryView GetRegistryView()
  {
    // Determine the registry view based on the application's target platform
    bool is64BitProcess = Environment.Is64BitProcess;
    return is64BitProcess ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
  }

  private string GetCurrentUserSid()
  {
    try
    {
      // Get the current user's Windows identity
      WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

      if (windowsIdentity != null)
      {
        // Get the user's SID
        return windowsIdentity.User.Value;
      }
      else
      {
        // Handle the case where the Windows identity is not available
        return string.Empty; // or throw new Exception("Windows identity not available");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Handle or log any exceptions that may occur
      Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve current user's SID: " + ex.Message);
      return string.Empty; // or throw the exception if necessary
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71500768/10024425